# Spring cache Caffeine integration without SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, caffeine-cache

I want to integrate Caffeine Cache in my Spring 5 application. I know that I need the CaffeineCacheManager, but i dont have the class. The only way i found is to add the SpringBoot Starter Cache package to the pom, but i dont want to use Spring Boot.

I have this Spring packages in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Is any way to **have CaffeineCacheManager class wihouth Spring Boot**? Thanks.

Actually i am using this code to configure the cache:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(
        new ConcurrentMapCache(
                "categorias",
                Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofDays(1)).maximumSize(100).build().asMap(),
                false
        ),
        new ConcurrentMapCache(
                "ciudad",
                Caffeine.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).build().asMap(),
                false
        )
    ));
    
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main spring cache implementation is located in spring-context dependency. You should only setup that cache manager and use @Cacheable annotation.
For examples see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial
Let me know if you need code example of connection Caffeine cache with spring cache mechanism.

**CaffeineCacheManager configuration:**

CaffeineCacheManager is located in

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And caffeine dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineConfig() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeine) {
        CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
        caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine);
        return caffeineCacheManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the repply. I updated the question with the code i use to config the cache. The problem is that wihouth CaffeineCacheManager i cant use default configuration. SimpleCacheManager is very basic. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. spring-context-support was the library i was lacking.

Comment: Perfect! Anytime!

Comment: Does it work on Spring 4 version?